# pinning columns in ng-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to pin first two and last two columns in a ng-grid by default. I know  I can set the desired columns as pinned like the code below

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
     enablePinning: true,
    columnDefs: [{ field: "name", width: 120, pinned: true }
    //...
  };
```

But i don't want the user to change it like in the example below

http://plnkr.co/edit/UfFnsZ?p=preview

i mean the columns should be fixed and the users shouldn't be able to edit it. I searched but coudn't find any example. Is it possible?If so can someone plz help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a custom `headerCellTemplate` for this particular column.

```
    var hc_nopin="<div class=\"ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}\" ng-style=\"{'cursor': col.cursor}\" ng-class=\"{ 'ngSorted': !col.noSortVisible() }\">\r" +
    "\n" +
    " <div ng-click=\"col.sort($event)\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" class=\"ngHeaderText\">{{col.displayName}}</div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    " <div class=\"ngSortButtonDown\" ng-click=\"col.sort($event)\" ng-show=\"col.showSortButtonDown()\"></div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    " <div class=\"ngSortButtonUp\" ng-click=\"col.sort($event)\" ng-show=\"col.showSortButtonUp()\"></div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    " <div class=\"ngSortPriority\">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    " <div ng-class=\"{ ngPinnedIcon: col.pinned, ngUnPinnedIcon: !col.pinned }\"  ng-show=\"col.pinnable\"></div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    "</div>\r" +
    "\n" +
    "<div ng-show=\"col.resizable\" class=\"ngHeaderGrip\" ng-click=\"col.gripClick($event)\" ng-mousedown=\"col.gripOnMouseDown($event)\"></div>\r" +
    "\n";

    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePinning: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: "name",
      width: 120,
      pinned: true,
      headerCellTemplate: hc_nopin
    }, {
      field: "age",
      width: 120
    }, {
      field: "birthday",
      width: 120
    }, {
      field: "salary",
      width: 120
    }]
    };
```

In the custom `hc_nopin` template I just removed the `ng-click` command for switching the pinning-state.
If you don't want the pinning icon too, just remove the respective line.

Here is the forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0t8qC0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help...I just have one doubt...sorry to bother you again...now pinning first two columns is not a problem(thnks again) but if i pin last colum then the grid-columns get sorted and the last pinned column moves next to the first two pinned columns pushing back the remaining columns..

Comment: Yes i noticed that too. This might be expected behavior but it seems like an annoying bug too me. I'll see what I can find out about this.

Comment: it is an annoying bug actually...anyways thanks..looking forward to your reply...I am searching as well..will post it if i find any solution

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday for 2 days. Pinning a column to the right is not that easy. Maybe you look at this thread where @roblarsen came up with a hack that's not 100% perfect, but it may give you a hint on how to proceed. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/349 Notice that this needs some rewriting of the source code which I only recommend if it's absolutely necessary. Or, you give ui-table a try which can do this by default. http://berndwessels.github.io/angular-ui-table/

Comment: you are great....tht's exactly what i was looking for...i wish i could upvote but dont have enough points...@mainguy

Answer (score 3):

Or you can utilize the following css:

```
.ngPinnedIcon, .ngUnPinnedIcon{
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide all the icons for pinning and unpinning.  It works for me because I didn't want the user to ever change the pinning of the columns.